# attempt to index global ' self ' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I ran this code and it gave me an error attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)

```
hook.Add( "PostDrawOpaqueRenderables","2d3d", function( )  
    cam.Start3D2D( Vector( self.Entity:GetPos() ), Angle(0, -90, 90), 1 ) 

        surface.SetDrawColor( 255, 0, 255 )
        surface.DrawTexturedRect( 0, 0, 500, 500 )

    cam.End3D2D()

end)
```

Comment: Based on the code provide this doesn't seem to be a context were `self` would be anything but `nil`. What do you expect `self` to be? is this inside another function?

Comment: Use `function(self)` instead

Comment: @lhf Unlikely as `PostDrawOpaqueRenderables` hook does not pass anything that would contain an `Entity` member. I would suggest changing `self.Entity:GetPos()` to e.g. `LocalPlayer():GetPos()` and see if the result is satisfying (also unlikely, but we can't really know the author's intent).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `hook.Entity:GetPos()` fix this error.
`self` is a lua keyword, that appears in the method definition of a table.

Comment: The definition of `self` you provided in your answer is not correct. `self` is simply an arg passed to a function. it is commonly passed using `:` like in `sometable:method()` which is just syntactic sugar for  `sometable.method(sometable)` explained here at the end of function definitions: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11. `self` is also not a keyword https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1